What is the simplest symbolic expression for "for some choice of disjoint pairings of $i$, $j$, $k$, $n$, each variable equals its partner"?
I'm not sure if this is appropriate here since the question is about aesthetics and efficiency more than it's about mathematics, but here it is anyway.
It's been surprisingly hard to find a short, self-contained mathematical expression to use $\sum\limits_{\text{here}}$, that's logically equivalent to $(i=j\wedge k=n)\vee(i=k\wedge j=n)\vee(i=n\wedge j=k)$. The best one I've found is $\delta_{ij}\delta_{kn}+\delta_{ik}\delta_{jn}+\delta_{in}\delta_{jk}>0$, but it's still a fair bit longer than I want: $\sum\limits_{\delta_{ij}\delta_{kn}+\delta_{ik}\delta_{jn}+\delta_{in}\delta_{jk}>0}$.
Is it possible to have such a neat expression?

I agree with your expression $\delta_{ij}\delta_{kn}+\delta_{ik}\delta_{jn}+\delta_{in}\delta_{jk}>0$ but I don't understand what you mean with the $\Sigma$ with the latter expression...

The $\sum$ is just there to explain why I'm looking for something smaller and neater. Subjectively, having very long expressions as sum limits looks obnoxious and takes up a lot of space, reducing readability of the expression as a whole.

IMHO, your "tensor-like" expression is perfect but maybe I have ill-understood your question...

I do like it overall, but it still involves some typesetting problems. I'm also looking into TeX solutions, so the mathematical solution might not be that important (but it would still be cool to have one).

If pressed I might write something like $\sum_{\text{pairings}}$ and just explain in the accompanying text what that means.

Yeah, I might do that if I can't find a neater expression, which seems likely. Here's what I'm actually doing:
$$\left({\sum_{\substack{{i,j,k,n}\in S(3,4,8),\vee\(1\leq i,j,k,n\leq8,\wedge\\delta_{ij}\delta_{kn}+\delta_{ik}\delta_{jn}+\delta_{in}\delta_{jk}>0)}}}x_{1,i}x_{2,j}x_{3,k}\right)_{n=1}^8$$
$$=\left({\sum_{{i,j,k,n}\in S(3,4,8)}}{x_{1,i}x_{2,j}x_{3,k}}+{\sum_{\substack{1\leq i,j,k,n\leq8\\delta_{ij}\delta_{kn}+\delta_{ik}\delta_{jn}+\delta_{in}\delta_{jk}>0}}}x_{1,i}x_{2,j}x_{3,k}\right)_{n=1}^8$$

In the end, I discovered that if I relabeled each point in my structure and use bitwise XOR, I don't have to deal with this complicated expression at all because the bitwise XOR on any three integers always produces the last one in the block (or the desired value when the integers aren't all different). It goes beyond the scope of this question though, so I'll leave the deeper context out in this case.

Much nicer. $$\left({\sum_{\substack{i,j,k\in\mathbb{Z}8\i\oplus j\oplus k=n}}}a_i b_j c_k\right){n=1}^8$$
